# No connection to Bitcoin network from known Tor IP?

Tags: network, connection, tor

I have a very fast home Internet connection. I decided to share my bandwidth by setting up a Tor relay on an unused machine on my home network. Any connection I make from my home connection to an external internet site now appears to come from the IP address of a known Tor relay (it is not an exit node).

From this IP, I cannot connect to Bitcoin peers anymore, neither with the Core client nor with the Schildbach wallet on my phone when logged into the home Wifi. I always get 0 connections to the network and no new blocks. It is not just slower to connect; leaving Core open overnight didn't allow it to find any peers.

Do other Bitcoin peers regularly block connections from known Tor nodes? How do I debug this?

EDIT: Sorry about the noise, I solved this myself. When setting up the Tor node, I also made some changes to my firewall settings. Bitcoin didn't manage to get out through the firewall anymore. I have enabled connections to port 8333 now, and everything works again.